# Calling specific object by ID from a JSON file in my js

Tags: javascript, json

I am making a trivia game, and I am trying to pull questions and answers using a local json file. First, I did this test to confirm the file was working and get a basic understanding of what I am trying to do:

```
 $.getJSON('/trivia.json', function(data) {
   var items = [] 
   $.each(data, function (item, i) {
     items.push('<p id="' + i.order + '">' + i.question + ' - ' + i.correcta +  '</p>');
   });

 $('<p/>', {
  'class': 'my-new-list',
   html: items.join('')
 }).appendTo('#example');});
```

That worked in displaying all of the different question/answer combos from the json file (so all five questions + answers as `<p>`. Since I want to only show one question at a time as if someone were playing trivia, I will next want to only call a specific question at a time. Let's say I wanted to only show the the question/answer from id=1 and the json file looked like so:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "order": 1,
    "question": "Who was the only American President to learn English as a second language? ",
    "answer1": "John Quincy Adams",
    "answer2": "Martin van Buren",
    "answer3": "William McKinley ",
    "answer4": "Andrew Jackson",
    "correcta": "Martin van Buren",
    "published": "2014-11 04",
    "url": "http://example.com/trivia_demos/1.json"
}]
```

Each subsequent question in my json file follows that structure, so my belief is that I need to change the "id" attribute in the items.push function. From looking at some documentation, I can't see how to integrate that specific value into my function.

Any idea how to do that (use the id to pull only the first question + correcta) or accomplish such with a different method?

Answer (score 1):

Check this link [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/atulbnar/u6yefb7g/1/) I have added functionality for next do similar for previous button functionality.

// SAMPLE HTML CODE

```
<input type="button" id="btnNext" value="next"/>

<input type="button" id="btnPrev" value="prev"/>

<br/>

<div id="container">
    <div id="child" class="1"></div>
</div>
```

// JS CODE

```
var data=[{
    "id": 1,
    "order": 1,
    "question": "Who was the only American President to learn English as a second language? ",
    "answer1": "John Quincy Adams",
    "answer2": "Martin van Buren",
    "answer3": "William McKinley ",
    "answer4": "Andrew Jackson",
    "correcta": "Martin van Buren",
    "published": "2014-11 04",
    "url": "http://example.com/trivia_demos/1.json"
  },{
    "id": 2,
    "order": 1,
    "question": "Who was the only American President to learn English as a second language? ",
    "answer3": "John Quincy Adams",
    "answer2": "Martin van Buren",
    "answer1": "William McKinley ",
    "answer4": "Andrew Jackson",
    "correcta": "Martin van Buren",
    "published": "2014-11 04",
    "url": "http://example.com/trivia_demos/1.json"
  },{
    "id": 3,
    "order": 1,
    "question": "Who was the only American President to learn English as a second language? ",
    "answer2": "John Quincy Adams",
    "answer1": "Martin van Buren",
    "answer3": "William McKinley ",
    "answer4": "Andrew Jackson",
    "correcta": "Martin van Buren",
    "published": "2014-11 04",
    "url": "http://example.com/trivia_demos/1.json"
  }];

// inside document.ready

var index=$("#child").attr("class");
//alert(data.length);
//loading data associated with index
var resultSet = $.grep(data, function (e) {
    return e.id=='1';
});
$("#child").html("Question :"+resultSet[0].question+" and first answer choice = "+resultSet[0].answer1);


$("#btnNext").click(function(){
var temp=$("#child").attr("class");
var index=parseInt(temp);

if(index==data.length)
{
    // Last Question
    // Only If you Need to return to first question
     var newindex=1;
    var resultSet = $.grep(data, function (e) {
        return e.id==newindex;
    });
    $("#child").html("Question "+newindex+" :"+resultSet[0].question+" and  answer choice = "+resultSet[0].answer1);  
    $("#child").attr("class",""+newindex); 
}
else
{
    var newindex=index+1;
    alert(newindex);
    var resultSet = $.grep(data, function (e) {
        return e.id==newindex;
    });
    $("#child").html("Question "+newindex+" :"+resultSet[0].question+" and  answer choice = "+resultSet[0].answer1);  
    $("#child").attr("class",""+newindex); 
}
});
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but here's the one part that is tripping me up. Since the var data in your example is actually being pulled from the  $.getJSON('/trivia.json', function(data); in my original code, is it feasible to format the var data = as a getJSON request instead? I just tried it but can't get the data to be delivered.

Comment: sorry i didnt get you.Can you post some code or explain what you are trying with example.

Comment: Sure. Take a look at my original post to see the full breakdown, but basically I will want to pull the question/answer from a locally hosted json file so that the data can continue being updated instead of within the same file. In my previous version, I called the json file and established 'var items' using: '$.getJSON('/trivia.json', function(data) {
   var items = []'. In your example, we establish the qs/as in the <script> with var data =. I want to make the data = the content of the trivia.json file to complete it, but can't figure out how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) available to arrays. We'll wrap it in a function so that you give an id and the list of trivias and it picks out the one with that id.

```
function getTrivia(id, items){
    var filtered = items.filter(function(item){
        return item.id == id;
    });
    return filtered[0];
}

getTrivia(1, items); //the question/answer with id 1
getTrivia(10, items); //the question/answer with id 10
```

To describe briefly how it works, `items.filter` will give back an array of all the items where the return value is true--in this case `item.id == id`. Ideally this will only be an array with one element. If for some reason it isn't, it will return the first trivia element when there are duplicate id's or `undefined` if there are no trivias with that id. You can change this behavior, of course, to whatever you please by altering `return filtered[0]`.